# Unwanted text keeps appearing when trying to pull body

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3, sanity

When pulling `<p>{{ post.body }}</p>` from sanity, it should just pull in the body text, right? Or am I missing something a bit more important?

```
<template>
  <Header />
  <h1>This is the blog page!</h1>
  <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post._id" class="post">
    <div class="post-img">
      <img :src="$urlFor(post.mainImage).url()" :alt="`${post.title}`" />
    </div>
    <div class="post-text">
      <div class="post-text__title">
        <a :href="`${post.slug.current}`"
          ><h2>{{ post.title }}</h2></a
        >
      </div>
      <div class="post-text__description">
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const query = groq`*[ _type == "post" ]{title, slug, mainImage, body} | order(_publishedAt desc)`;
const { data: posts } = await useSanityQuery(query);
</script>
```

Everything else seems to be fetched  as it should and appears just fine, but the result should be a few lines from the initial post body. But instead I receive;

```
[ 
    { "children": [ 
        { "text": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.", 
          "_key": "c937925bd4db0", 
          "_type": "span", "marks": [] 
        } ], 
        "_type": "block", 
        "style": "normal", 
        "_key": "7e69e0de1965", 
        "markDefs": [] 
    } 
]
```

I'm not sure as to why it's also pulling everything else within the block.

Answer (score 0):

Sanity uses Portable Text for the rich text content and you need to do serialization before displaying it on the front end.

You can find more on the subject here: https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-block-text